# Foreach in List<t> facebook friends

Tags: asp.net

Hi folks
I am fairly new to C# advanced topics. This is what I am trying to do.. 
Get Facebook friends data and insert into db. 
For getting the friends from FB, i am using json.

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture,link&access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);                    
Friends frnds = js.Deserialize<Friends>(json);
```

Now how do I insert this frnds in the database
I have the following class file Friends.cs

```
namespace TestConnect
{
    public class Friends
    {
        public List<Friend> data { get; set; }   
    }
    public class Friend
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string picture { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }

    }    
}
```

Now if I do `foreach(Friends lf in data)` foreach has a getenumerator missing error 
Please suggest some way..Not sure if I am complicating it.. which I tend to do sometimes

Thanks
SC

Comment: 20 questions * (0 accepts + 0 votes) = 0 help usually :)

Comment: What is `data` in your foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data` in your example is the `Friends` member `data` then try this:

```
foreach(Friend f in frnds.data)
{

}
```

Comment: @Abe.. Thanks for ur answer and the rest of the junk ---Ok thanks guys for all ur stupid comments,